# Efficient method of accessing matrix or x/y values

Tags: java, matrix

Below is a comparison matrix :

```
     val1,val2,val3
val1,1,   5,   4
val2,5,   3,   5
val3,4,   5,   6
```

What is an efficient method off accessing values in this matrix. So for example val2,val1 returns 5 & val3,val1 returns 4

Here is a possible method signature :

```
public int getValue(String name1 , String name2){

.....

return value
}
```

and to call :

```
 getValue(val2 , val1)
```

which returns 5

A possible solution is to create a map data structure where the key is combination of the val strings :

```
map.put("val1,val1" , 1);
map.put("val1,val2" , 5);
map.put("val1,val3" , 4);
```

And then to return the values in method getValue defined above use :

```
public int getValue(String name1 , String name2){

return map.get(name1+","+name2)
}
```

Is this a viable solution or is there a more viable option. The matrix in question is of the order 100000 x 100000 dimension

Update1 : the matrix is symmetric

Update2 : the matrix could be sparse in places

Comment: This doesn't look viable to me.

Comment: @peter.petrov Why? Assuming that not all items are filled in, this should work (not too efficiently, but still it should work).

Comment: Are col/row names always gonna be `valX` or can they be arbitrary? If the former, why not parse the `X` part of the name?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight true but he didn't say how sparse that matrix will be. if it's 50% filled in - still a problem

Comment: @peter.petrov No, definitely not fifty percent: with ten billion cells, he's going to see a problem even if it's filled by 0.1%. It needs to be extremely sparse in order for this approach to work.

Comment: @Adrian - The example matrix you provided is symmetrical. Does "comparison matrix" imply the matrix is symmetric? If so, you can trade off a more complex lookup to and cut the storage requirement in half.

Comment: Why not use: HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> . Then you can access constant time (variation of the Map reduce algorithm)

Comment: @faisal could you expand on your comment please ? How is this a variation of the Map reduce algorithm?

Comment: @faisal, you should make your comment an official answer.  I could do it, but I don't think it's right to get credit for your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an actual *matrix* to store the data?

```
// create and fill a matrix of the right dimensions
int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];

// create a map that maps row/col names to indexes
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("val1", 0);
map.put("val2", 1);
map.put("val3", 2);

// the actual method is straightforward
public int getValue(String name1 , String name2) {
    int i = map.get(name1);
    int j = map.get(name2);
    return matrix[i][j];
}
```

Also, be aware that the expected size of your matrix (100.000 x 100.000) is *huge*, the memory usage will be the greatest of your concerns, it might be infeasible to create such a big data structure in memory unless the matrix is sparse, in which case a different approach needs to be devised.

Comment: Matrix - 100000x100000 = 10,000,000,000 ints? Each int is 4 bytes so 40 GBs?

Comment: @peter.petrov if the matrix is sparse, then there are better alternatives. But if it is not (as seems to be the case, judging by the sample in the question) then an `int[][]` will be the cheapest way to store all those values, cheaper than using a `Map`

Comment: True but maybe both approaches are not feasible. But yes, array will be cheaper than a map. Map is out of question here unless the structure will be quite sparse.

Comment: @Óscar López the matrix could be sparse in places, what are the "better alternatives" ?

Comment: @Adrian I'd advise you take a look at the topic of [sparse matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix), perhaps a good book in numerical analysis would be useful. Your problem is non-trivial, the matrix you intend to build is far too big

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating one `Map` structure, I think you should create two: One to hold the row labels and another to hold the column labels:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> rowMap, colMap;
rowMap = new HashMap<>();
colMap = new HashMap<>();
// Populate the maps with the row and column key-value pairs
public T getValueAt(String row, String col) {
    return myMatrix[rowMap.get(row)][rowMap.get(col)];
}
```

Comment: The syntax for accessing values in a matrix is wrong, it should be `m[i][j]`, not `m[i, j]`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez someone comes from C# apparently :-)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Thank you (sorry for the mistake); someone corrected it (before myself)

Answer (score 1):

If not all items of your matrix get filled I would suggest to implement a special class with `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods like this

```
class Cell {
    String first;
    String second;

    public int hashCode() {
        return first.hashCode() ^ second.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object c) {
        if (c instanceof Cell) {
            return first.equals(((Cell)c).first) && second.equals(((Cell)c).second);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then you can define your matrix as

```
Map<Cell, Integer> matrix;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `String`, you could make your own small class:

```
class MatrixIndex {
  public final int x, y;

  public MatrixIndex(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return x ^ (y << 16) ^ (y >>> 16);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceOf MatrixIndex)
      return o == this
          || (o.x == x) && (o.y == y);
    else
      return false;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  }
}
```

This will allow much faster access inside most maps (like `HashMap`s) as building the reference, comparing two indices, and hashing a given index is much faster than with String objects.

You can also do something similar with `String` objects if it is really strings you want to use for the X and Y indices of the matrix, but my guess is you really want to get to it by integer.

**This is only for populating the matrix itself! And it will only be good to use if your matrix is very sparse!** If you also want to have labeled axes, you should *also* do what Barranka suggested, with Maps for row & column indices from `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> map`.

```
public Integer getValue(String name1 , String name2){
  HashMap<String,Integer> row =map.get(name1);
  if(row!=null) return row.get(name2);
  else return null;
}
```

This is constant time.